# How to add dynamic greater than filter (filter box) in apache superset?

Tags: apache-superset

Has superset changed its folder locations and interface? From a youtube tutorial, I found these options available in filter box:
[image]

But why my filter box looks like this:
[image]

I want to apply a filter box which gives me flexibility to apply a filter over ranges. For example, this is my table:
[image]

I tried to apply the filter as shown below:
[image]
[image]
[image]
But how it works is this way:
[image]
When we look at time filter:
[image]
It works well and offers tons of customization, I was just curious if we can dynamically filter time then why not other values. Please do let me know if you have something for this.